# Need to perform n-gram on the dataset

Tags: r

I need to perform n-gram on the below dataset.

`Column 1`

`Electronic, socket, clamp, cooler`

`Actuator, cylinder, valve`

`Hydraulic, electronic, cooler`

`Actuator, Pnematic, cylinder, valve`

I need the output like below,

```
Column 1

Electronic_socket, socket_clamp, clamp_cooler

Actuator_cylinder, cylinder_valve

Hydraulic_electronic, electronic_cooler

Actuator_Pneumatic, Pneumatic_cylinder, cylinder_valve
```

Comment: You can learn how here: https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html

Comment: Hi @Rlearn, has the solution below helped or can I amend something to help improve it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an example assuming your data is in column_1 of a data.frame, the following should create your n-grams using base R:

```
# build original data as a data.frame with 1 column
df <- data.frame( column_1 = 
                     c("Electronic, socket, clamp, cooler",
                       "Actuator, cylinder, valve",
                       "Hydraulic, electronic, cooler",
                       "Actuator, Pnematic, cylinder, valve"), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 lov <- strsplit(df$column_1, ', ', fixed=TRUE)

 sapply(lov, function(x){paste0(x[ -length(x) ], '_', x[-1])})
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Electronic_socket" "socket_clamp"      "clamp_cooler"     

[[2]]
[1] "Actuator_cylinder" "cylinder_valve"   

[[3]]
[1] "Hydraulic_electronic" "electronic_cooler"   

[[4]]
[1] "Actuator_Pnematic" "Pnematic_cylinder" "cylinder_valve"
```

#### Explaining this solution:

Think about dealing first with just one line at a time e.g. 
if you have the words from one line already in a vector:

```
    x <- c("Electronic", "socket", "clamp", "cooler")
```

Your desired output is:  `Electronic_socket, socket_clamp, clamp_cooler`

```
x[ -length(x) ]  #gives you all but the last word
# [1] "Electronic" "socket"     "clamp"     

x[-1]  #gives you everything except the first word
# [1] "socket" "clamp"  "cooler"

#paste them together with a "_" between yields your desired output for that line
paste0( x[ -length(x) ], '_', x[-1] )
# [1] "Electronic_socket" "socket_clamp"      "clamp_cooler"
```

Comment: Hi, I got the solution. In case I have to perform 3 grams instead of 2. Can we alter the code?

Comment: If you're asking "how to create trigrams using base R?" that might make a great new SO question ;-) But if you just want to get quick results for n-grams use the package and excellent tutorial @JohnSpring suggested https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html